# Laravel undefined variable $articles

Tags: php, laravel

I'm busy with my own news system and I'm using Laravel 5. I'm quite new to Laravel and using tutorials to walk my way through it. Now I'm having this error "Undefined variable: articles".

Here is my ArticlesController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
{
    return view('pages.news');
    }
}
```

Here is my news.blade.php

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
<!-- Post -->
<div class="blog-item">
    <!-- Post title -->
    <h2 class="blog-item-title font-alt">
        <a href="news-single.html">{{ $article->title }}</a>
    </h2>
    <!-- Post data -->
    <div class="blog-item-data">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 December</a>
        <span class="seperator">&nbsp;</span>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> John Doe</a>
        <span class="seperator">&nbsp;</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
        <a href="#">Category</a>, <a href="#">Category</a>
        <span class="seperator">&nbsp;</span>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 5 Comments</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Media gallery -->
    <div class="blog-media">
        <ul class="clearlist content-slider">
            <li><img src="images/portfolio/full-project-1.jpg" alt="Blog image"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Text intro -->
    <div class="blog-item-body">
        <p>{{ $article->body }}</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Read more -->
    <div class="blog-item-foot">
        <a href="news-single.html" class="btn btn-mod btn-round btn-small">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I have tried couple things, such as removing everything and starting over. Nothing really did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass the variable to your view, else the view does not "know" the variable. Like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('pages.news', ['articles' => Article::all(),]);
    }
}
```

Reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#basic-controllers).

Answer (score 2):

You do not pass any data from the controller to the view, so do something like this:

```
$articles = Article::get();

return view('pages.news', ['articles' => $articles]);
```

Or:

```
return view('pages.news', compact('articles'));
```

Or:

```
return view('pages.news')->with('articles', $articles);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views